# Comma-Delimited List with "and" concatenated before Last Element in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I've been using LISTAGG to make a comma delimited list for a report, but I have been requested to add "and" before the last element. So right now my output for 3 different cases is:

```
First, Second, Third
First, Second
First
```

But now the desired output is:

```
First, Second, and Third
First and Second
First
```

I thought about doing a Case When, that checks the count and if there are 2, then use 'and' as delimiter, but how could I go about doing this for more than 2 elements?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try regexp_replace:

```
select regexp_replace('First, Second, Third', ',([^,]+)$', ' and\1') from dual;
```

`,([^,]+)` finds last comma + anything but comma until the end of the string and replaces it with "and" + the first expression in "()"

(It should work if your expr doesn't contain commas)

The whole example:

```
select regexp_replace(listagg(name, ', ') within group (order by name), ',([^,]+)$', ' and\1') from (
  select 'First' name from dual
  union all select 'Second' from dual
  union all select 'Third' from dual
);
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly!! What I did was insert the LISTAGG that I already had into the regexp_replace, so it looked like this:

regexp_replace(LISTAGG(GIVING.NAME, ', ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY GIVING.NAME), ',([^,]+)$', ' and\1')